# How to find Motorola AVD since site change?

Tags: android, sdk, motorola, android-virtual-device

I'm using the Eclipse IDE and trying to emulate the Motorola Droid Turbo, but all MotoDev references are pointing to a new consumer site with no information. Does anyone know where I can get Motorola AVD's?